# Why does the for loop keep stopping at else statement?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

main()
{
string str1;
char strArray[80];
cout << "Enter string: ";
getline(cin, str1);

transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str1.begin(), ::tolower);

for(int i = 0;i < str1.length();i++)
{
    if(str1[i] == ' ' || str1[i] == ',' || str1[i] == '.')
    {

    }
    else
    {
        strArray[i] = str1[i];
    }
}

cout << strArray;
return 0;
}
```

The for loop keeps stopping after it finds a space, comma, or period. Could someone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: Changing the string length while iterating over the string seems very dangerous.

Comment: @Jeff There is no danger. Look at a string "a,b,c". After the first erase at `i=1` you should have a string "ab,c" with the length of 4. Dangerous would be using an iterator for a STL container that becomes invalid on erase.

Comment: @Jeff it would be dangerous if iterators were used, but using an integer index and comparing to `str1.length()` should be OK.

Comment: @harper I realize it's not the same danger posed by an actual iterator.  However, I don't like the fact that you have to reason through it to prove that it's safe.  I'd rather just not change it and know that it's safe.

Comment: @Jeff I don't see why it could be a "lesser" danger as well as I don't know something "a bit" dead. The call to `str1.length()` might inhibit some optimization, but the original code (incl. `str1.erase();`) checks a condition at each loop iteration. Would you elaborate a bit where you see the danger?

Comment: @harper I don't think it's resilient to change and just poor form overall. Let's say you changed the length enough that i was now outside the range of the array. While the code would still work, I think it's weird that you're now relying on the < operator to check your work. This is a transformation and should be treated as such. I would treat the source array as immutable and select the data into a new array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `i` keeps incrementing even though you erased a character from the input. It's not actually stopping, just skipping a character. Since `strArray` now has a hole in it, it's likely that the hole is filled with `0` thus ending the C-string. P.S. this behavior is not guaranteed and you might end up with completely different results on another run of the program.

Comment: Also, the final string is never explicitly nul terminated which is another issue with this code sample.

Answer (score 0):

When you call erase it affects the container, so you need to handle this. erase() returns the iterator to the next element after the deleted one, so you should use that instead:

```
int i = 0;
for(string::iterator it = str1.begin(); it != str1.end(); )
{
    if(*it == ' ' || *it == ',' || *it == '.') 
    {
        it = str1.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
        strArray[i++] = *it++;
    }
}
strArray[i] = '\0'; // terminate string
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post which string you input for str1? Cause I try run it and it run well without stop. The only proplem I found with your code is that you erase the char in the loop which will lead to wrong result string.

Answer (score -1):

You are erasing characters from the string while still continuing to increment the counter. Remove `++i` from the `for` loop. Put it under the `else` clause.

```
for(int i = 0;i < str1.length();)
{
   if(str1[i] == ' ' || str1[i] == ',' || str1[i] == '.')
   {
      str1.erase(i, 1);
   }
   else
   {
      strArray[i] = str1[i];
      ++i;
   }
}
strArray[str1.length()] = '\0';
```

Comment: Creates an infinite loop for me.

Comment: That is odd. I don't see anything wrong with the logic in the code.